# Filtering a list of list in python

Tags: python

I have got a list of list like this

```
testList=[[1,'test',3],[4,'test',6],[1,6,7]]
```

My requirement is to create another list of list as follows

```
rstList=[[1,'test',3],[1,6,7]]
```

That is, list having element 'test' need to be appended **only once** to the rstList.

Comment: How do you determine which `test` you want to keep? Is it just the first one you come across?

Comment: @AlexL How you know what "need to be appended only once" you are OP?

Comment: @Denis I just added 'only' - the 'appended once' was already there.

Answer (score 3):

```
flag = True
for item in testList:
    if ('test' in item and flag) or ('test' not in item):
        flag = False
        rtList.append(item)
```

Comment: Lol, you just copy paste decision below.

Comment: @Denis What? Isn't this different to the other answers?

Comment: @Denis: Try to run both the routines see the output yourself :P

Answer (score -1):

```
testList=[[1,'test',3],[4,'test',6],[1,6,7]]
rstList = []
for item in testList:
    matched = False
    for result_item in rstList:
        if item[1] == result_item[1]:
            matched = True
    if not matched:
        rstList.append(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope following code would work for you

```
def genNewList(v):
    test = False
    ret = []
    for el in v:
        if ('test' in el):
            if(test == False):
                ret.append(el)
                test = True
        else:
            ret.append(el)
    return ret

testList=[[1,'test',3],[4,'test',6],[1,6,7]]

print 'Original list', testList
print 'New list', genNewList(testList)
```

[Here](http://www.evaluzio.net/doc/272307cfd0454a078d77) you can run the script, and/or fork and play around with it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you only want to keep the the first sub-list with 'test' element, here's one approach:

```
def func(x):
    global foundTest
    if 'test' not in x: return True
    elif not foundTest: foundTest = True; return True
    return False

foundTest = False
rstList = filter(func, testList)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
filter(lambda x: x if 'test' in x else None, testList)
```

Comment: Could someone explain what is wrong with this solution, since it is getting downvotes? Because i'm interested.

Comment: @Gjordis I didn't downvote, but I imagine it is because it doesn't achieve the result the OP is looking for, and there's no need to use an `if` - this is equivalent: `filter(lambda x: 'test' in x, testList)`

Comment: @Gjordis (The first argument to `filter` should be a function that returns a bool, not x or None)

Comment: @Alex L Are you know about dynamic casts in python and how standart datatypes casts to bool, I think you don't.

Comment: @Denis I know `bool(None) == False`, but that's not the issue. What if x were a type that cast to False (i.e. 0 or a custom object)?

Comment: @Denis - Your code's output does not match OP's expected output.

Comment: @Denis That still doesn't explain why you'd need to use an `if` here. `lambda x: 'test' in x` is more efficient.